# How to make Dwarsligger (flipback book) in latex?

Tags: formatting

I mean a form of book in which the page of one page from a conventional book is printed across two pages, so the text appears to be parallel to the spine. Accordingly, the numbering of pages occurs on the basis that two pages opened vertically are one page.
I can't even imagine how this can be done in latex?

Comment: doesn't that just amount to printing the document landscape and binding along the long edge?

Comment: and only printing the (halved) page number on every other  page

Comment: but how to print "the (halved) page number on every other page"? considering the need  for imposition?

Comment: see answer  I just posted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this, if I understand correctly

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[OC]{}
\fancyfoot[EC]{\huge---\the\numexpr\value{page}/2\relax---}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. Looks beautifull. You just created Dwarsligger for latex! Very impressive!

Comment: Just like its author

Comment: Is it possible to minimize the bottom margin on odd-numbered pages and minimize the top margin on even-numbered pages so that the vertical spread of the book looks almost like one single page? (like in a Dwarsligger)